# Unable to uploading video files due to error 413

Tags: wordpress, iis, iis-10

When i try to uploading a video file i get an error 413. Caused by an error in IIS i have been unable to resolve this error and have tried the following.

I have already tried to override the uploadreadahead file in both the IIS setting and the website settings. None of which had an effect as described below.

I expected the override to work but instead i got an internal server error also when i put it in the IIS settings it seems to ignore or not apply the settings as im still unable to uploading video files due to error 413.

Anyone got any idea on how i can fix this?

Comment: Is this you trying to upload a video to the Media Library using the Wordpress UI?  If so, what does it show as your max upload size when trying to upload new media?  You can find out by going to Media -> Add New

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to run below command:appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webserver/serverruntime /uploadreadaheadsize:1048576 /commit:apphost. If this command is still not working, I suggest you could post the details information about the file size of the video file you have used.